# focal regression: USB connection to APC SmartUPS failing after reboot

Tags: 20.04, usb, ups, nut

I'm managing about ninety Dell servers distributed worldwide, currently in the process of being upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04LTS xenial to Ubuntu 20.04LTS focal.
Each server's power supply is protected by an APC SmartUPS connected via USB and monitored by nut in order to shut down cleanly in case of power failure.
This works quite well on the servers still running xenial.

On those running focal, there's a frequent problem with the USB connection to the UPS not coming up after a reboot. Specifically:

- During system startup, the kernel does not detect the UPS and instead complains in /var/log/syslog:

  ```
  kernel: [    2.239216] usb usb1-port4: couldn't allocate usb_device
  ```
- `upsmon` periodically complains in syslog:

  ```
  upsmon[1105]: Poll UPS [ups@localhost] failed - Driver not connected
  ```
- The SmartUPS does not show up in the output of `lsusb`:

  ```
  a-schmidt@somewhere:~$ lsusb
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1604:10c0 Tascam
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1604:10c0 Tascam
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1604:10c0 Tascam
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  ```
- Running `sudo upsdrvctl start` manually reports it cannot find the device:

  ```
  a-schmidt@somewhere:~$ sudo upsdrvctl start
  Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.4
  Network UPS Tools - Generic HID driver 0.41 (2.7.4)
  USB communication driver 0.33
  No matching HID UPS found
  Driver failed to start (exit status=1)
  ```

Doing a USB bus reset via the command sequence:

```
echo '0000:00:14.0' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
echo '0000:00:14.0' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
```

helps every time. The UPS is detected, as witnessed by the /var/log/syslog message:

```
kernel: [20025.662161] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [20025.838902] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=051d, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 0.01
kernel: [20025.838907] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: [20025.838910] usb 1-4: Product: Smart-UPS_1500 FW:UPS 04.1 / ID=1018
kernel: [20025.838913] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: American Power Conversion
```

It shows up in `lsusb`, and `upsdrvctl start` connects successfully:

```
a-schmidt@somewhere:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1604:10c0 Tascam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1604:10c0 Tascam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1604:10c0 Tascam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
a-schmidt@somewhere:~$ sudo upsdrvctl start
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.4
Network UPS Tools - Generic HID driver 0.41 (2.7.4)
USB communication driver 0.33
Using subdriver: APC HID 0.96
```

`upsmon` stops complaining and everything is fine again.

What could be the reason for this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Comment: Would the casters of the three closing votes mind sharing which community rule they think the question violates?

Comment: From what I can see the close votes concern bug reports which should be reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a kernel bug already reported to Launchpad here:

[[regression] USB device is not detected during boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1939638)

and to the kernel.org Bugzilla here:

[Bug 214021 - The USB devices fail to be detected during boot](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214021)

So the solution would be to wait until a fixed kernel is available.

Note: I tried adding an `@reboot` crontab entry to run the USB bus reset command sequence after each reboot as a stopgap measure but that did not work out because `@reboot` happens too late in the startup process when the `nut` driver is already running, so I dropped that idea.